# How to add TinyMCe to CakePHP admin forms?

Tags: cakephp, web, tinymce

I want to add power to my CakePHP website by adding the TinyMCe editor to the forms in the Admin.

I found the plugin available at http://cakedc.com/eng/downloads/view/tinymce and followed the steps available in that website but the form doesn't show!

Regards

Comment: can you please paste your whole config for the tinymce?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use a plugin for this, just get the TinyMCE code and set it up in your template something like this (chopped a bit for clarity):

```
<?php
echo "\n".$javascript->link('tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',false);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">


    $().ready(function() {
        $('textarea').tinymce({
            // Location of TinyMCE script
            //          // General options
            theme : "advanced",
            plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,...",

            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,image,link,unlink,... :
"cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,... ",
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                theme_advanced_resizing : true
             });
        });
    </script>
?>
```

I actually do this as an element so that I can just drop it in where required. Study the TinyMCE wiki and api - they're incredibly useful.